# How to autoupdate android app without going to playstore like facebook doing?

Tags: android

I want to update code without going to play store and doing manually update.

So what should i do? Anyone have a idea about it

Comment: You can go to play store settings, and set the auto-update parameter. If you enable it, all apps will update automatically.

Comment: @Jack Any source where FB is updating it automatically without the help of play store?

Answer (score -1):

Have you increased the version code and version number in the App level gradle file. When you increase the version google play store automatically checks the installed version on your device and the version uploaded on the Google Play store. If uploaded version is greater than installed version it automatically updates the App.